# A comparison between the words "custom", "tradition" and "practice"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I was wondering if you could let me know if the both choices below work in my sentence without any change in meaning:
- In my country, it’s a........for women to get married in white.

> - custom
> - tradition
> - practice

For me, based on dictionary definition they all can be used, but I have no idea which one would be the most natural.

Asking this question I was going to find out when shall one use each one of these words and how they differ in meaning?

[source: Cambridge Dictionary]
P.S. I've manipulated the example.

Comment: "Custom" sounds more formal. "Tradition" is probably the most commonly used word out of all three, but don't quote me on this. And "practice" would probably be used with "common practice," i.e., "...t's (a) common practice...."

Comment: You should summarize your understanding of each word based on definitions or usage that you checked, rather than just ask which one is better to use. My guess is that it will be locale and context dependent.

Comment: One more very useful question which was closed by the moderators.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all 3 could be used in the sentence.  As for the differences, this was answered in a comment to your question...

"Custom" sounds more formal. "Tradition" is probably the most commonly used word out of all three, but don't quote me on this. And "practice" would probably be used with "common practice," i.e., "...t's (a) common practice...." – Teacher KSHuang